# My springboot docker swarm application cannot find a file defined as a secret in my docker but it can find the same file is mounted as volume

Tags: spring-boot, docker-swarm, docker-volume, docker-secrets

I have a springboot application that needs to read the content of a certificate during its initiation.

If I add the certificate file through a volume it finds the file.

If I add the certficate file through a secret (because the info should be secret) it does not find the file:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

So to try to understand if the secret was being created ok, what I did was to create both the file from a volume and the file from  secret (they are in different folders). And the app tries to read the file from the volume that I know it works so I can go in to the docker to check the secret in the other folder exists.

You can see the volumes and the secret folder with the file on both of them and that they have the same level of permissions:

folder with the file of the volume:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  4 14:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May  4 14:26 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 1034 May  4 14:26 cert.perm
```

folder with the file of the secret:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 May  4 08:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May  4 14:26 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 1034 May  4 08:26 cert.pem
```

You can see that the only difference is that the folder where the file lives the volume one is owned by the user, and the secrets one by the root.

But this shoult not have impact whether or not the app can read the file in one location or another.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added this secret to the swarm? If you do a 'docker secret ls' can you see this secret? Reference:https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret/